# Should I tell my vineyard consultant to spray my fruit trees with the sulfur he sprays on the vineyard?

Tags: fungus, apples, organic, grape-vine

We have a very small (450 vines) pinot noir vineyard that we are raising organically.

My vineyard consultant has people spray the vines with sulfur a few times each season.

Last year, one of my apple trees (about 7 years old) just broke and fell over - presumably from a fungal infection ...

I am wondering - we have apple trees and pear trees and we have never done anything but water them and give them some basic fertilizer - should we just spray the apple and pear trees with the same sulfur that we spray the vines with ?

It seems to me that as long as those guys are there spraying 450 vines, why not spray 20 more trees ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, YES. Apart from sunlight, water and fertilizer, good care also includes a regular schedule of spraying your apple and pear trees if you wanna have a healthy fruit tree thats able to produce lots of pest-free fruits. I live in an arid climate and come spring time, aphids start showing up on almost everything. If i dont start spraying, those aphids would multiply by a thousands and wreck havoc on all the tender new growth. No use waiting on beneficial insects to do their part cause they're still asleep.